# RFM analysis using R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and new here. 
 Below are the source code. However, the results are incorrect with 99.9% with a ranking of 1 in Frequency and Monetary and nothing ranked as 5 in R.  Can someone please help? Really appreciate!!

```
setwd('\\Users\\stang\\Documents\\R\\RFM')
bmdata = read.csv("Customer sales 103116-103117.txt",header=TRUE,sep=",")
dim(bmdata) [1] 1094964       3

str(bmdata) 'data.frame':   1094964 obs. of  3 variables:  $ customer_ID: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...  $ sales_date : Factor w/ 366 levels "1/1/2017 0:00:00",..: 86 66 81 82 84 85 105 116 122 124 ...  $ sales      : num  182 120 91 63 58 56 251 24 269 113 ...
```

create recency

```
bmdata$Recency <- round(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),bmdata[,2],unit="days")))
head(bmdata)
  customer_ID sales_date sales Recency
1           1 2016-11-03   182     368
2           1 2016-11-11   120     360
3           1 2016-11-25    91     346
4           1 2016-11-26    63     345
5           1 2016-11-28    58     343
6           1 2016-11-29    56     342
```

creation of Recency, Frequency and Monetary

```
bmdataR <- aggregate(bmdata[,4],list(bmdata$customer_ID),min)
names(bmdataR) <- c("customer_ID","Recency")
head(bmdataR)
  customer_ID Recency
1           1      10
2           2      13
3           3      12
4           6      37
5           7      25
6           9       7

bmdataF <- aggregate(bmdata[,2],list(bmdata$customer_ID),length)
names(bmdataF) <- c("customer_ID","Frequency")
head(bmdataF)
  customer_ID Frequency
1           1        52
2           2        39
3           3       117
4           6        47
5           7        52
6           9        33

bmdataM <- aggregate(bmdata[,3],list(bmdata$customer_ID),sum)
names(bmdataM) <- c("customer_ID","Monetary")
head(bmdataM)
  customer_ID Monetary
1           1  6432.75
2           2  3005.60
3           3 27889.52
4           6  5573.05
5           7  6513.20
6           9  2889.40
```

combined RFM per unique customer ID

```
bmdataRFM <- data.frame(bmdataR,bmdataF,bmdataM)
```

calculate sales per visit

```
bmdataRFM$salespervisit <- bmdataRFM$Monetary/bmdataRFM$Frequency
```

combination R, F, M

```
temp <- merge(bmdataF,bmdataR,"customer_ID")
bmdataRFM2 <- merge(temp,bmdataM,"customer_ID")
head(temp)
  customer_ID Frequency Recency
1           1        52      10
2           2        39      13
3           3       117      12
4           6        47      37
5           7        52      25
6           9        33       7
# creation of R,F,M rank
bmdataRFM$rankR <- cut(bmdataRFM$Recency,5,labels=F)
bmdataRFM$rankF <- cut(bmdataRFM$Frequency,5,labels=F) bmdataRFM$rankM <- cut(bmdataRFM$Monetary,5,labels=F)
#Analysis
groupRFM <- bmdataRFM$rankR*100 + bmdataRFM$rankF*10 + bmdataRFM$rankM
bmdataRFM <- cbind(bmdataRFM,groupRFM)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you share your data (or a sample, or fake but similar) to copy and paste in our R? This could be helpful to detect your problems. Furthermore, why do you create `bmdataRFM2` if you do not use it if I've understood reading your code (despite I'd use it rather than `bmdataRFM`, because I prefere use `merge()`) ? Lastly, `head(bmdataRFM)`  is what you want rather than `head(temp)` to see, right?

Comment: Thanks @nihil!!

Comment: @nihil - I can't paste all the data. see partial data below. Thank you and hope you can help

Comment: "customer_ID","sales_date","sales"
"0000000001",11/3/2016 0:00:00,"182"
"0000000001",11/11/2016 0:00:00,"120"
"0000000001",11/25/2016 0:00:00,"91"
"0000000001",11/26/2016 0:00:00,"63"
"0000000001",11/28/2016 0:00:00,"58"
"0000000001",11/29/2016 0:00:00,"56"
"0000000001",12/2/2016 0:00:00,"251"
"0000000001",12/3/2016 0:00:00,"24"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried all your script, maybe it is a problem of data, however, I created some fake data similar to your:

```
set.seed(12)
customer_ID <- sample(1:500, 500, rep = TRUE)
sales_date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2017/12/01'), by="day"), 500)
sales <- sample(20:400, 500, rep = TRUE)
bmdata <- data.frame (customer_ID,sales_date,sales)
head(bmdata)
  customer_ID sales_date sales
1          35 2016-08-15    43
2         409 2016-09-02    79
3         472 2016-11-20   327
4         135 2016-05-08   191
5          85 2016-12-25   217
6          17 2017-05-22   242
```

Then, as you , I calculated with your script RFM:

```
# recency
bmdata$Recency <- round(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(),bmdata[,2],unit="days")))

bmdataR <- aggregate(bmdata[,4],list(bmdata$customer_ID),min)
names(bmdataR) <- c("customer_ID","Recency")

# frequency
bmdataF <- aggregate(bmdata[,2],list(bmdata$customer_ID),length)
names(bmdataF) <- c("customer_ID","Frequency")

# monetary
bmdataM <- aggregate(bmdata[,3],list(bmdata$customer_ID),sum)
names(bmdataM) <- c("customer_ID","Monetary")

# RFM dataframe
bmdataRFM <-merge(merge(bmdataR,bmdataF),bmdataM)

# this is commented because I've not used it.
# bmdataRFM$salespervisit <- bmdataRFM$Monetary/bmdataRFM$Frequency


# here the ranks
bmdataRFM$rankR <- cut(bmdataRFM$Recency,5,labels=F)
bmdataRFM$rankF <- cut(bmdataRFM$Frequency,5,labels=F)
bmdataRFM$rankM <- cut(bmdataRFM$Monetary,5,labels=F)

 > head(bmdataRFM)
  customer_ID Recency Frequency Monetary rankR rankF rankM
1           1     338         1      145     1     1     1
2           2     633         1      268     3     1     1
3           5     573         1      119     3     1     1
4           7     439         1      290     2     1     1
5           8     580         3      835     3     3     3
6          10     344         1      192     1     1     1
```

And, as you can see, it seems everything works.

```
round(prop.table(table(bmdataRFM$rankR))*100,2)
    1     2     3     4     5 
28.00 23.08 19.08 15.69 14.15 

round(prop.table(table(bmdataRFM$rankF))*100,2) 
    1     2     3     4     5 
61.23 26.46  9.85  2.15  0.31 

round(prop.table(table(bmdataRFM$rankM))*100,2)    
    1     2     3     4     5 
68.62 26.77  3.69  0.62  0.31
```

Now, the grouped labels:

```
groupRFM <- bmdataRFM$rankR*100 + bmdataRFM$rankF*10 + bmdataRFM$rankM
bmdataRFM <- cbind(bmdataRFM,groupRFM)
head(bmdataRFM)
  customer_ID Recency Frequency Monetary rankR rankF rankM groupRFM
1           1     338         1      145     1     1     1      111
2           2     633         1      268     3     1     1      311
3           5     573         1      119     3     1     1      311
4           7     439         1      290     2     1     1      211
5           8     580         3      835     3     3     3      333
6          10     344         1      192     1     1     1      111
```

And now, you can see how the individuals are:

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(data=analysis, aes(x=reorder(Var1,Freq), y=Freq, label = Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + coord_flip() + geom_text()
p
```

[image]

So it seems everything works, maybe you can look at your data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will retry. Have you ever tried k-mean clustering or the "rfm" package in RStudio to do a RFM analysis?

Comment: Yes, I currently use RFM analysis as you've done, and k-means, using the `kmeans()` function. If my answer is not what you wanted, we can try to solve it.

Comment: Hi, I just realized that you are missing some combinations like 555, 543, 544, 533 etc?

Comment: Yes, because you're creating the rank for each variable (R, F, M), so in each variable there are all the ranks (1,2,3,4,5) but this does not guarantee the presence of each of the 5^3 combinations.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback!! I also tried doing it using packager 'rfm' but ran into problems. Wondering if you mind taking a look at my other case. Thank you!!  https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20260079

Comment: Hi @slee if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Just did! Thanks again @nihil